# Problemas WARN DispatcherServlet.noHandlerFound(1120) No mapping found for HTTP request with URI

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Estoy trabajando con una aplicación web que usas `Spring`, usa entre otras las siguientes dependencias (librerías)

```
<!-- spring mvc -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring Security -->
        <dependency> 
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId> 
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId> 
            <version>4.0.4.RELEASE</version> 
        </dependency> 

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
        <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
        <version>11.2.0.4</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
```

El problemas es que no sé a que es debido pero me sale el error alguna vez (no siempre)

> WARN  DispatcherServlet.noHandlerFound(1120)  No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/XXX/XXX.htm] in DispatcherServlet with name 'XXX'

Comment: Lograste resolver el problema?

Comment: ¿A qué ruta quieres acceder y cómo hiciste el mapeo?